# Microsoft LAPS installation error

Tags: windows, security

I want to deploy Microsoft LAPS for our organization, I prepared all pre-requisites.

When I install LAPS on domain controller (windows server 2012 R2), I can't. I get the error message:

> The system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation.

I checked GPO's, disabled GPO's, disabled Anti-virus, tried with different privilege users but still the same error.

Please support me in this regard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to keep your domain controller clean from software installation as much as possible.
If you are trying to install LAPS on your DC, this will not have any benefits because a DC dont have a local administrator account.

Instead you should do the below:

- Install LAPS on management machine (any domain computer) be sure to check all installation features including the laps powershell module. You will use this machine to configure laps for your organization.
- Configure a GPO to deploy LAPS agent on your clients.
- Configure another GPO that will push LAPS password policy to your clients.

You can refer to this guide: [LAPS implementation](https://www.configjon.com/microsoft-laps-step-by-step-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

gpedit.msc

Computer > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Installer
Turn Off Windows Installer: Enabled: Disable Windows Installer: Never

May need to run `gpupdate /force`.